# How to update new plotline values instead of removing and adding new ones in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a dynamic value for a quote. Horizontal line indicates the current position on a line chart. To move it i have to remove and add last one each time i receive new. I need to animate transition of this plotline, that's why it should not be removed and created again.

That's how it looks now:

```
                    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('current-price');

                    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                        value: parsedData.quote,
                        color: 'black',
                        width: 0.5,
                        id: 'current-price',

                            useHTML:true
                        },
                        zIndex:100
                    });
```

Comment: Hi, I think that you can use svgElem of your plotLine and use Highcharts.animate() method for animating this plotline. Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/vqerk3zz/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can update the options directly and then update the axis:

```
var newValue = (chart.xAxis[0].options.plotLines[0].value + 1) % 10;
chart.xAxis[0].options.plotLines[0].value = newValue;
chart.xAxis[0].update();
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aviram26/v8xte4hL/

Answer (score 2):

we've all probably seen the following page(s), they dont really contain an answer.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines

@Aviram had a good solution, but my example contains a lot more data , which causes slow redraws.

Ive found that the `update()` call does a redraw/rerender in some cases ([source link](https://github.com/mstahv/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js#L6841-L6855)), which can be very expensive and slow for large plots. i used the following code to update just the plot line, and it seems to update the plot line very quick. The reason i update `plotLines` and `plotLinesAndBands`, as in some cases when you redraw the lines/axis things need to match.

```
[chart].xAxis[0].options.plotLines[0].value = newVal;   
[chart].xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value = newVal;
[chart].xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].render();
```

The `render` function used above is called on redraw anyway ([source link](https://github.com/mstahv/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js#L8511-L8513)), so were not doing anything crazy here!

Answer (score 0):

> **Update:** The solution below is best suited for **Highcharts**. During subsequent comments and clarification, I learned the original poster is using **Highstock**, which does not support the `scatter` plot type. I was not successful in adapting this solution to their code, which was an `areaspline` chart using data points updated in real time.

Rather than using a plot line, I'd suggest creating a new series that will serve as your line. That way, you can update the series as needed and it will pick up the native animations that Highcharts provides.

Here's a working example using a basic line chart:  http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/ws3e1wns/

Below is the code for the new series, which uses the `scatter` type. Note that I've disabled the markers, added a line width, and set `showInLegend` and `enableMouseTracking` to `false` so it won't be seen by your users as a "true" data series.

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        // scatter plot line to serve as moveable plot line
        type: 'scatter', 
        data: [[0,10],[11,10]], 
        lineWidth: 1, 
        marker: {
            enabled: false          // hide the markers (to show only the line)
        },
        showInLegend: false,        // hide in legend
        enableMouseTracking: false  // prevent user from interacting with this line
}]
```

Whenever you click the button in this fiddle, it will move the new series line up 10 points on the y-axis. To do so, I update both ends of the line:

```
// button handler
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    y = 30;
$('#button').click(function () {
    y += 10;
    // update both ends of the scatter line
    chart.series[1].data[0].update([0,y]);
    chart.series[1].data[1].update([11,y]);
});
```

As you can see, the line animates when it is moved.

I hope this is helpful and useful for you!

Comment: That looks like a good idea. Could you please show how to make it in my case, with my variable. I'm not very good in understanding this code...

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich I'd need to see more of your chart code in order to match it precisely to your variable(s). Could you please provide that in a fiddle?

Comment: Yes, please. https://jsfiddle.net/fedorbass/xxp0pts0/   Please have a look at first commented line

Comment: Just thought, that i didn't mention you in last message

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look over it yet. I'll try to do so over the weekend.

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich My solution isn't working as expected with your Highstock project. Since my answer was done with Highcharts in mind, and unfortunately doesn't solve your problem, I can delete it. I apologize that I wasn't able to be of further help.