# Highcharts draggable annotaion how to move by steps?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, annotations

I would like to make the annotations move by a certain step and not stop in between two columns in axis.

For example, the x axis is [0, 10, 20, 30]. When dragging the annotation, I want its point to change directly from {x: 10, y: 10000} to {x: 20, y: 10000} without going to x: 15. i.e. make the annotation a bit **sticky** to the column and not sitting between columns.

I also need to get the current annotation point so I can update some other element.

I tried the solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825116/how-to-update-new-plotline-values-instead-of-removing-and-adding-new-ones-in-hig) but it doesn't work.

Here is my current code. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/roy-jaide/pen/jONGLoB)

`enter code here`

Edit 1:
Thanks to the solution from @ppotaczek, the annotation can move by steps now. Here is the updated code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roy_jaide/7yt5v3c8/2/). What needs to be refined is when dragging the annotation too fast, it cannot keep up with the mouse. Is it because of the performance of Highcharts.redraw() method and how can we solve this?

Another unsolved question is -> how to get the current point of the annotation? It seems the annotation object doesn't provide any value about that. All I can think of is keep a record of the initial point, then everytime the annotation is moved by a step, update the record. Is there a better way?

```
//this code can deal with vertical and horizontal annotations now.
Highcharts.Annotation.prototype.onDrag = function(e) {
if (
  this.chart.isInsidePlot(
    e.chartX - this.chart.plotLeft,
    e.chartY - this.chart.plotTop
  )
) {
  var translation = this.mouseMoveToTranslation(e),
    xAxis = this.chart.xAxis[0],
    yAxis = this.chart.yAxis[0],
    xStep = 1,
    yStep = 1000,
    pxStep = xAxis.toPixels(xStep) - xAxis.toPixels(0),
    pyStep = yAxis.toPixels(yStep) - yAxis.toPixels(0);

  if (!Highcharts.defined(this.potentialTranslation)) { //not defined
    this.potentialTranslation = 0;
  }

  if (this.options.draggable === 'x') {
    this.potentialTranslation += translation.x;
    translation.y = 0;
    if (Math.abs(this.potentialTranslation) >= Math.abs(pxStep)) {
      translation.x = (this.potentialTranslation > 0) ? pxStep : -pxStep;
      this.potentialTranslation = 0;
      //this.potentialTranslation = undefined;

      if (this.points.length) {
        this.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
      } else {
        this.shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
          shape.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
        });
        this.labels.forEach(function(label) {
          label.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
        });
      }
    }
  }
  if (this.options.draggable === 'y') {
    this.potentialTranslation += translation.y;
    translation.x = 0;
    if (Math.abs(this.potentialTranslation) >= Math.abs(pyStep)) {
      translation.y = (this.potentialTranslation > 0) ? -pyStep : pyStep;
      this.potentialTranslation = 0;

      if (this.points.length) {
        this.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
      } else {
        this.shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
          shape.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
        });
        this.labels.forEach(function(label) {
          label.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  this.redraw(false);
  }
}
```

Edit 2:
Thanks to @ppotaczek again! The "mouse moving too fast" issue is solved now. I apply his updates and also my idea of how to get the annotation value into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roy_jaide/7yt5v3c8/15/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `Highcharts.Annotation.prototype.onDrag` method:

```
(function(H) {
    H.Annotation.prototype.onDrag = function(e) {
        if (
            this.chart.isInsidePlot(
                e.chartX - this.chart.plotLeft,
                e.chartY - this.chart.plotTop
            )
        ) {
            var translation = this.mouseMoveToTranslation(e),
                xAxis = this.chart.xAxis[0],
                step = 0.5,
                pxStep = xAxis.toPixels(step) - xAxis.toPixels(0);

            if (!H.defined(this.potentialTranslation)) {
                this.potentialTranslation = 0;
            }

            this.potentialTranslation += translation.x;

            if (Math.abs(this.potentialTranslation) >= pxStep) {
                translation.y = 0;
                translation.x = (this.potentialTranslation > 0) ? pxStep : -pxStep;
                this.potentialTranslation = 0;

                if (this.points.length) {
                    this.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
                } else {
                    this.shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
                        shape.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
                    });
                    this.labels.forEach(function(label) {
                        label.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
                    });
                }
            }

            this.redraw(false);
        }
    }
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vmon2chx/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks for your answer, it works! I have also update my code using your solution. [link]https://jsfiddle.net/roy_jaide/7yt5v3c8/2/[/link] But the only imperfection of your solution is that if dragging too fast, the annotation cannot keep up with the mouse. Any solutions to that?

Comment: I also wonder how to get the current point of the annotation? It seems the annotation object doesn't provide any value about that. All I can think of is keep a record of the initial point, then everytime the annotation is moved by a step, update the record. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi @Roy.L.T, It should work better in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mj954cf1/ Your idea is quite good, the annotation does not have any connections with points.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks for the update, it does work much better now. I update my code to reflect the updates, and also apply my previous idea of getting the annotation value. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roy_jaide/7yt5v3c8/14/)